# Is there any way to run the /execute as run command in Minecraft with a non built-in command?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-java-edition-server, minecraft-mods

I would like to run an mv tp command to the closest player using the command block, however multiverse doesn’t recognise @p or @a. I would like to find a way to use it from a command block on the closest player.(I use Spigot)

Comment: Some plugins override default Minecraft commands but you can still use them like this: /minecraft:tp @p ... Just change the namespace (minecraft:) depending on if you want to use the plugins commands or the default game commands.

Comment: So you're basically just trying to do this? `/execute as @a run mvtp <arguments>` What is the issue with that? Does it not work as expected? What happens instead?

Comment: @FabianRöling it wont recognize it, says command not found. /execute as run only allows Minecraft commands, and mvtp doesn't recognize at p.

Comment: That sounds like a bug in the mod, you should report it.

Answer (score 1):

This has been reported as something which will not by patched by spigot head developer. https://hub.spigotmc.org/jira/browse/SPIGOT-4327

luckily, the following tool exists: https://github.com/JorelAli/1.13-Command-API